# Windows Command SC, how to check errorlevel

Tags: windows, windows-command-prompt

I'm looking for a way to check the returncode / errorlevel of the SC command in a DOS script. How can I get this information ?

Answer (score 3):

In **most** cases you can just check the value of %errorlevel%.

```
echo %errorlevel%
```

However, your comment seems to be correct that the %errorlevel% is useless for **sc** in particular.  I'll keep the links included below for people who still want to read about %errorlevel% and application exit codes, but it appears I have not answered your question.

---

Application Exit Codes - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line

This is an explanation of *exactly* what **errorlevel** is - http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx

Comment: if you try the errorlevel with the SC command you will find out that it doesn't work. Why the SC command is so special in this case I don't know. working with net start / net stop the %errorlevel% is reliable. (I'm aware of the speciality if this old fellow and use it accordingly).

Comment: You can always obtain the errorlevel; it's virtually impossible for a program not to have one. But it is very well possible that the errorlevel is always 0. Having non-zero errorlevels is special.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are mostly after the information whether the command succeeded or not. In that case you can simply use

```
if not errorlevel 1 ...
```

which will execute the `...` part if the last exit code was `0`. (It gets a little more complicated than that, but you can ignore that for the most part).

Checking the pseudo-variable `%errorlevel%` can be dangerous because if someone set a *variable* with that name before, its value will overshadow the pseudo-variable expansion.

Comment: thanks, aware of this, however as mentioned above, SC command is not playing nicely with errorlevel.